# How to group and count with underscore.js or javascript

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

> Input

```
memo = [
  {
    home_goalie: "Rinne Pekka",
    home_team: "Nashville",
    visitor_goalie: "Rask Tuukka",
    visitior_team: "Boston",
    team_name_event: "Boston",
  }, {
    home_goalie: "Rinne Pekka",
    home_team: "Nashville",
    visitor_goalie: "Rask Tuukka",
    visitior_team: "Boston",
    team_name_event: "Boston",
  }, {
    home_goalie: "Rinne Pekka",
    home_team: "Nashville",
    visitor_goalie: "Rask Tuukka",
    visitior_team: "Boston",
    team_name_event: "Nashville",
  },
  {
    home_goalie: "Price Carey",
    home_team: "Montreal",
    visitor_goalie: "Rinne Pekka",
    visitior_team: "Nashville",
    team_name_event: "Montreal",
  }
];
```

> Desired transformation

I would like to process my array in way that JavaScript creates an array of goalies and team pairs, adding counts of goals that have been made against the goalie.

Basically I know it would require to write a script that count by team_name_event and when home_team === team_name_event it returns home_goalie key to array and add count in the next field. When this has been done for visitor_team as well player_name can be grouped.

However, I am rookie with JavaScript and Underscore, so I would appereciate all help!!!

> Sample output

```
memo = [{
  player_name: "Rinne Pekka",
  team: "Nashville",
  goals_against: 3
}, {
  player_name: "Rask Tuukka",
  team: "Boston",
  goals_against: 1
}, {
  player_name: "Carey Price",
  team: "Montreal",
  goals_against: 0
}];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stack Overflow is here to help, not write code for you.

Comment: using _.forEach on _.unique() and _.filter().length within the _.forEach you should be able to do your job.

Comment: I have tried many things, but it quite a problem as I dont know javascript or underscore so well yet (I am a rookie) and this would be the one last thing what I have to do for my application, which should be ready tomorrow.